# Wordpress Plugins Showing in FTP not in Dashboard

Tags: plugins, ftp, wordpress

I recently uploaded Google XML Sitemaps and my plugins all disappeared from my dashboard!?

I was super curious so I checked the plugins folder from FTP and all the plugins were still listed...yet none are being shown in the backend of the Wordpress site or working throughout the site!?

Whenever I try to upload them from a created zip file it is saying..."The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found." ?

I have valuable information in the settings of some of these plugins so I'd like for them to be restored as is.

Comment: Have you delete the google sitemap? There must be a php error stopping the rest from showing methinks.

Comment: Hey Gavin..I delete the google sitemap and noticed there was a virus that threw a chunk of code into the top of every php file on the site.  Looks like it's going to have to be a healthy reinstall.

Comment: Unlucky. Change all passwords relating to the site first, ftp passwords, everything. Rather safe than sorry. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Gavin I'll do that

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the Google XML plugin from the FTP and then recheck in admin. Otherwise restore a previous version of your website, you should always have a backup of your site available.

If however you fail to retrieve your plugins, then there are a few things you can do.

1- FTP into your plugin folder, rename the plugin folder to something else, create a new plugin folder and move any plugin into the new plugin folder, refresh the WP admin and see if it works

2- Check the file permissions in your plugins, they should be 0755.

If all fails it is better to reinstall the plugins and delete the previous ones.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Ahsan.  The last backup was from a couple months ago but seeing as I found the culprit is a virus I'm going to go with a fresh install of wordpress, the theme, and all the plugins.

Comment: Ask your hosting provider to remove the virus, they usually help out in that case.